# Mysql Database not creating table [messy code]

Tags: mysql

I tried to add this:

```
   -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Nov 09, 2013 at 04:43 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.16
-- PHP Version: 5.3.8

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `rezzion`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `punishments`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `punishments` (
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `punisher` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `server` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

to my database "rezzion" & for some reason i'm getting this error:

[image]

Anyone know why it's doing this? I have my database set to utf8-bin & it's name is rezzion... I'm confused why the code above isn't working?

Comment: it's in punishment's it's strictly just a log. when they have a punishment it will go to that username & I don't have the ability to change usernames, only display names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error starts, at least, here:

```
`username` varchar(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

This is not allowed in MySQL. And, besides, you're declaring primary key with another column:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Auto Increment can only be used on a INT change it to a integer and your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` my only be used with number types. You are applying it to a `VARCHAR` column. Also, you specify an "id" column as your primary key which does not exist.

You probably want it to look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `punishments` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `punisher` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `server` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(1024) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```